# Counting prime numbers in C++

Tags: c++, primes

How do I count all the "prime" numbers instead of displaying them?

Example:

```
cout << "there are 125 prime numbers";
```

I'm using the number 1000 because I want to find out how many prime numbers it has.

I don't want to display the found prime numbers but I want to know how many have been found.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int a=2 ; a < 1000 ; a++)
    {
        bool prime = true;

        for(int c=2 ; c*c <= a ; c++)
        {
            if(a % c == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(prime) cout << a << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your formatting man.. it's.. pretty bad.

Comment: You know this is WYSIWYG and there's a box of formatting help on the right as you write your question, right?

Comment: why don't you actually TRY asking the question in a right manner. besides, your question can be answered with simple Googling. and yeah, check out sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: That is why I'm asking or else I wouldn't be saying anything...I don't see why post comments that have nothing positive to provide for an answer to my problem...

Comment: Just use a counter for each prime number. Increment the counter instead of displaying each prime number. At the end, print the value of the counter. This really has nothing to do with prime numbers.

Comment: You do not need to determine all the individual primes, which is slow.  Look for different versions of the Prime Counting Function, which simply returns the count.

Answer (score 2):

Reformatting your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int a = 2; a < 1000; a++) {
        bool prime = true;

        for (int c = 2; c*c <= a; c++) {
             if(a % c == 0) {
                 prime = false;
                 break;
             }
         }

         if(prime) cout << a << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of printing it out each time through the loop, you need to make a variable to count each time the number is prime.  Start by adding a variable outside of your outer for loop:

```
int main() {
    int num_primes = 0;
    for (int a = 2; a < 1000; a++) {
```

Next, instead of printing whenever a number is prime, just increment the counter:

```
if(prime) {
    num_primes += 1;
}
```

Finally, just before you return from main(), print out the number of primes:

```
cout << num_primes << endl;
return 0;
```

While this definitely looks like your homework, I hope you learn something from this.

Comment: I did thanks... Most of the code was layout by me is just that when it comes down to details I tend to loose the guide..There aren't many guides explaining c++... thanks for clarifying my code...

Comment: can I ask you what "+=" does ?

Comment: It is short hand for "num_primes = num_primes + 1".  This isn't the best way to do it, but I was trying to change your code as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
#include < iostream>
#include < iomanip>
#include < string>
#include < sstream>
#include < fstream>
#include < math.h>
#include < stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int count=0;
    for (int a=2 ; a < 1000 ; a++)
    {
        bool prime = true;
        for (int c=2 ; c*c <= a ; c++)
        {
            if(a % c == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
         }
        if(prime) count++;
    }

    cout <<"No of prime numbers : "<< count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked... I would never guessed this sort of details...

Comment: Please, avoid the use of **"Try [Insert code snippet here]"** answers. Provide some explanations. If not do that, OP is suggested to only copy-paste the answer, without understanding and thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just increment a counter instead of printing the value. You can also obtain a fairly decent approximation of Euler's totient function using the equation N/(log(N)-1)...

Comment: so how do I exactly implement a counter... I'm new to the  C++ and the vocabulary...

Comment: See RadhaKrishna's post, above.